# How to create mobile version of exist site?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile, sencha-touch, jqtouch

I have not a experience on the mobile development. There is a site that opens on a mobile **scattered**. I should create Mobile Version of that site. I have 2 question to start:

**1.** How can I create a mobile version of that site? To take existing site HTML and to add some attribute them? How do 2 versions (web and mobile) do the same operations?

**2.** Which Mobile Framwork do You recommend that is easy and well?

Answer (score 2):

1. You should have a look at [CSS Media Queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html) and make your website responsive.
2. I can suggest [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), a responsive front-end framework

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, the main thing I would do is make sure your widths are in percentages. This way your site will adjust based on the size of the window (the web has always been naturally responsive).
- To make a mobile version of your existing site it will take some adjustments using CSS, so that it looks good on different size screens. This is basically retrofitting, [heres](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/18/retrofit-a-website-to-be-responsive-with-rwd-retrofit/) a good article on that.
  Basically resize your browser (with your site opened up), and where ever it starts looking funny, unreadable, or you feel a change could be made to enhance the look just add a breakpoint using [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) as mentioned in the above response.
- I've always heard good things about Foundation, as mentioned above. Depending on the complexity of your site you could do without and just roll your own responsive, mobile version of your site.